# gcc and extconf fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gcc, extconf.rb

This is the mkmf.log file that shows when the ERRORS For gcc and extconf are generated when I am trying to install Rails.  'sudo gem install rails'.  I have not seen an answer that gets to the response about the mkmf.log and provides a solution.

I have installed Homebrew, RVM, Ruby, gcc, Xcode Tools, etc.  These Errors are thrown during the rails install.  I get some understanding
about this and how I can complete the Rails 5 installation?

mkmf.log file:
    "gcc -o conftest -I/Users/fulbriw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-   2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14 -I/Users/fulbriw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/b$
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/haven/.sm/pkg/active/lib'
    ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libz.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /usr/local/lib/libz.dylib
    checked program was:
    /* begin */
    1: #include "ruby.h"
    2:
    3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
    4: {
    5:   return 0;
    6: }
    /* end */

```
"gcc -I/Users/fulbriw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14 -I/Users/fulbriw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -I/U$
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */
```

Thank you, I have been working to resolve this since this morning.  Any help will be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Never do

```
sudo gem install rails
```

let bundler install rails for you.

1) make sure the version of Rails you need is in your Gemfile.

2) run `bundle install` from the command line in your project.

If you get an error for not having bundler you may need to run `gem install bundler` first

3) ensure you are using the correct version of Rvm

run `rvm list` and ensure that your current version matches what is specified in the gem file.

Comment: I am still getting the "extconf" error.  I have loaded rails-5.0.0 to my project root directory and to the Gemfile directory in  /usr/local/bin/.   I have followed everyone's directions and it get's back to this. Using RVM v1.27.0,

Comment: Did you try to sudo gem uninstall rails then following the steps I outlined above?

Comment: all seemed to go well, until the end when I received:

extconf failed, exit code 1     again. 

Why do I keep getting this error.   I have, however, gotten further buy executing the 'sudo gem uninstall rails' and doing the re-install....yet in the end.... still the ame  extconf failed.   Is this a problem with my .bash_profile and path expressions?

Comment: Here is the latest export from the mkmf.log:

Comment: Just re-ran: gem uninstall rails, ran "bundle install' from project directory, using latest version of RVM, rvm list:

Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/fulbriw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.2.2'.

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.2.2 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

Comment: what is your path variable?  It seems you may not have added rvm to your path.